# How to add a string at the beginning of each line in a file

Tags: file, unix

I want to add a specific string at the beginning of each line in a file. So, if I have the below two lines in someFile.txt and want to add a date string 03/06/2012 with pipe-

```
Hello|there|john
Hello|there|joel
```

I would have-

```
03/06/2012|Hello|there|john
03/06/2012|Hello|there|joel
```

What would be the most efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
$ awk '{print "03/06/2012|" $0;}' input.txt > output.txt
```

Takes about 0.8 seconds for a file with 1.3M lines on some average 2010 hardware.

Answer (score 5):

```
sed -i 's/^/03\/06\/2012|/' input.txt
```

Comment: sed allows you to use any unused character instead of `/` as the field separator for of the `s` command.  That way you don't need to mess with escaping the `/`'s in the date.  e.g. `sed -i 's#^#03/06/2012|#' input.txt`

Comment: Yes that's a better solution. We can use any character. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

`perl -ne 'print "03/06/2012|$_"' input.txt > output.txt`

Just for fun, I benchmarked 10 runs in /tmp:

```
             Rate        awk perl_5.6.1        sed  perl_5.22  perl_5.20
awk        2.08/s         --       -10%       -10%       -26%       -32%
perl_5.6.1 2.32/s        11%         --        -0%       -17%       -24%
sed        2.33/s        12%         0%         --       -17%       -24%
perl_5.20  3.06/s        47%        32%        31%         9%         --
```

Tested using a 1.3M line input file created here:
`perl -le 'while (1){exit if ++$n > 1300000; print $n}' > input.txt`